# Read a single column of excel sheet using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet. I want to write a method which takes parameter as column number that to be read and return a array consist of all the data in that column.

And then to place that column element in xml sheet. How can I write a method to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Use Apache POI. You can find example in their usage page.

```
Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet1) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
    // Here you might have to use the cell number to limit what you want.
        CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getCellNum());
        System.out.print(cellRef.formatAsString());
        System.out.print(" - ");

        switch(cell.getCellType()) {
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
        break;
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
          System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
        } else {
          System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        }
        break;
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
        System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Certainly POI is the way to go with regard to reading excel spreadsheets from Java.

Answer (score 2):

You may find this answer helpful: [How to get columns from Excel files using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922692/to-get-columns-from-excel-files-using-apache-poi/5499524#5499524)

That has all the code you need to extract all the numeric values from one column, whether they're a number cell or a formula cell containing a number result. I suspect you'll need something like that.