# How to get the size or length of column in generated Excel file using POI Apache

Tags: java, apache-poi

I think my title is clear what I want to know. I already searched google and there's no answer to my problem.

I want to know how can I get the size or length of an specific column in POI Apache Java?

Comment: You mean width or height?

Comment: Do you mean width/height in pixels/points or do you mean the number of columns or rows?

Comment: @raffaele i mean number of Rows in a Column.

Comment: @user3238865 i mean number of Rows in a Column.

Comment: You can look into these two answers:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858846/how-to-calculate-number-of-rows-in-a-column-of-excel-document-using-java][1]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874074/count-number-of-rows-in-a-column-of-excel-sheetjava-code-provided][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858846/how-to-calculate-number-of-rows-in-a-column-of-excel-document-using-java
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874074/count-number-of-rows-in-a-column-of-excel-sheetjava-code-provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found out how to get the size of column in my on way. Post another answers if you have another one for future references.

```
int columnSize = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < row.getLastCellNum(); x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < row.length; y++) {
    columnSize = y;
  }
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought you cannot getheight for column.But you can getheight for Specific row . other way is use CellStyle to get Height(It can be done using top border+ bottom border+ font height) for specific cell.

Comment: i want to get the number of Rows in a Column.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct method for it.you have to iterate over all rows to know the size of column.

sample :

```
for (Cell cell : row) {
                ++COLUMNCOUNT;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
Row nextRow = iterator.next();
rowCount = firstSheet.getLastRowNum();
columnCount = nextRow.getLastCellNum();
```

Comment: getLastRowNum()// Using this number of rows can be calculated
getLastCellNum()// Using this number of columns for that particular row can be calculated

Comment: Please do not give code-only answers. Some context and/or explanation should be contained. And please edit your comment into the answer.